# Positiong text in HTML

Tags: html, css

i want to place text like (Home (spacing)  About (spacing)     Pictures) on webpage's menu bar
tell me how to do this.
i'm getting like this (home About Picture)

```
 <div id="menuOption" >
 <a href="www.google.com"><font color="#FFFFFF" >Home</font></a>
<a href="./download.html"><font color="#FFFFFF" >About</font></a>
<a href="./purchase.html"><font color="#FFFFFF" >Picture</font></a>
</div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `&nbsp;`

```
<div id="menuOption" >
   <a href="www.google.com"><font color="#FFFFFF" >Home</font></a>&nbsp;
   <a href="./download.html"><font color="#FFFFFF" >About</font></a>&nbsp;
   <a href="./purchase.html"><font color="#FFFFFF" >Picture</font></a>&nbsp
</div>
```

Or better use `<ul>` and make `<li>` `display: inline-block;` and use `padding`

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Pictures</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 5px 8px; 
   /* Change this according to your requirement, 
   5px is top, bottom and 8px is left, right */
}
```

> Note: `<font>` tag is deprecated, use CSS `color` property instead

Comment: @Pekka웃 I was editing my answer :) but this was really a small requirement so didn't wanted to confuse him :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 LOL I completely missed the `<font>` tag, thanks for notifying me

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use div and set float:left and apply padding.

```
<div id="menuOption" >
    <div style="float:left; padding-left:5px"><a href="www.google.com"><font color="#0000" >Home</font></a></div>
<div style="float:left; padding-left:5px"><a href="./download.html"><font color="#0000" >About</font></a></div>
<div style="float:left; padding-left:5px"> <a href="./purchase.html"><font color="#0000" >Picture</font></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Picture</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul {
    float:left;
}
ul li{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0 5px;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y5UEu/5/)